# C#: Regex for string with enclosing single-quotes (and escaping by doubling the quotes)

Tags: c#, regex, string, escaping

I did not found a regex for my problem. There are always example-regex for escaping with back-slash.

But I need escaping by doubling the enclosing-character.

Example: 'o''reilly'

Result: o'reilly

Comment: There's more than one type of regex.  What type are you using? Perl? R? Python? Emacs?

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: I use the regex classes from C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'(?:''|[^']*)*'
```

will match a quote-delimited string that may contain double-escaped quotes. So that's your regex to find those strings.

**Explanation:**

```
'      # Match a single quote.
(?:    # Either match... (use (?> instead of (?: if you can)
 ''    # a doubled quote
|      # or
[^']*  # anything that's not a quote
)*     # any number of times.
'      # Match a single quote.
```

To now remove the quotes correctly, you could do it in two steps:

First, search for `(?<!')'(?!')` to find all single quotes; replace them with nothing.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!') # Assert that the previous character (if present) isn't a quote
'      # Match a quote
(?!')  # Assert that the next character (if present) isn't a quote
```

Second, search for `''` and replace all with `'`.

Comment: Do I need: ")*     # any number of times." if the outer ")+" handles the repetition? BTW: If the outer ")+" is used, is a empty string possible?

Comment: @user437899: I had a typo in the concise version of the regex; it should be `)*` in both cases (although `)+` would still have allowed the empty string).

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Why should I use (?> instead of (?: ?

Comment: @user437899: Nested quantifiers have a risk of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Using atomic groups (as long as your regex engine supports them), that can be avoided. Another solution would be to use possessive quantifiers (`*+` instead of `*`), if your regex engine supports those instead.

Comment: Thank you again for the explanation. i use now '(?<String>(?:''|[^']*)*)' with a named group to get the string without quotes.

Comment: This causes "nothing to repeat" exception in python. Any workarounds? Edit: remove the inner * and this will work in python.